# Fluent interface in PHP Laravel querybuilder

Tags: php, laravel

If have this in my Laravel controller,

```
$employees = DB::table('employeed')->get();
```

does it mean that each record in $employees will have /inherit a fluent interface like the method table in DB::table? Is that the reason why I can do something like

```
{{ $employee->name}}
```

within a for loop of $employees where each record is assigned to $employee in a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you have an array of `stdClass` objects that you are iterating through, which is returned from that DB query. Each element in the array will be set as `$employee` as that loop iterates, assuming you are using a `foreach` loop like so:

```
@foreach ($employees as $employee)
    {{ $employee->name }}
@endforeach
```

**Update**

References for Query Builder and Eloquent

Query Builder

> the get method returns an array of results where each result is an instance of the PHP StdClass object.

Eloquent

> For Eloquent methods like all and get which retrieve multiple results, an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection will be returned. ...
>   Of course, you may simply loop over this collection like an array

[Laravel Docs - Query Builder - Retrieving Results](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#retrieving-results)

[Laravel Docs - Eloquent - Retrieving Multiple Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-multiple-models)

Comment: so both querybuilder and eloquent return stdClass for fetched records?

Comment: If you are using `get` with Eloquent you will get back a Collection (object) that may contain many Model instances (objects) or none.